# Xcode: Number of rows in section

Tags: plist, nstableview

i've got a plist dictionary with a couple of arrays like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>DebtA</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>NameA</string>
            <key>tel</key>
            <string>11111111</string>
            <key>email</key>
            <string>namea@abc.com</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>DebtB</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>NameB1</string>
            <key>tel</key>
            <string>22222222</string>
            <key>email</key>
            <string>nameb1@abc.com</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>NameB2</string>
            <key>tel</key>
            <string>22222223</string>
            <key>email</key>
            <string>nameb2@abc.com</string>
        </dict>
    </array>

.. more arrays

</dict>
```

What i want to achieve is that in a table view the number of rows in section is equal to the amount of items of the subsidiary arrays.

I've tried the following, without success.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[afdDict allKeys]objectAtIndex:section]numberOfItems];
}
```

How do i get the number of items (eg in DebtA, one. In DebtB two) of a given array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return [[[afdDict allValues] objectAtIndex:section] count];
```